# R: How to get and set named arguments in an expression

Tags: r, arguments, expression, named

I'm trying to understand how to work with R expressions. If I have a simple expression such as `exp <- quote(f(x=12))`, then `exp[[1]]` returns the function, `f`, and `exp[[2]]` returns the argument, `12`, but I don't know how to get at the argument name, `x`. Similarly, I don't know how to create the expression `f(x=12)` programmatically (without using `quote`).

Comment: In regards to the last part, you can assemble the call without `quote` by using `call("f", x = 12)`

Answer (score 2):

`as.list()` and `as.call()`, which convert calls to lists and lists to calls, are indispensable for this sort of [computing on the language](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Direct-manipulation-of-language-objects):

```
names(as.list(exp)[2])
# [1] "x"

as.call(list(as.symbol("f"), x=12))
# f(x = 12)

exp["y"] <- 4
exp
# f(x = 12, y = 4)
```

Comment: You don't even need `as.list`. "an object of mode "expression" is a list"

Comment: Also, to avoid `quote` as required in the question: `as.call(list(as.name("f"), x = 12))`

Comment: @Roland -- Good points, thanks. In practice, I still think using `as.list()` is usually helpful. (Compare the printed results of `exp[2]` and `as.list(exp)[2]` to see what I mean.)